# Reading byte file from DB2 stored procedure

Tags: file, stored-procedures, db2, blob

I'm new to DB2 stored procedures, but I've used IBM data studio to write a stored procedure that exports the content of a table that includes a Blob field to a flat file (using UTL_FILE) - which works fine.

An example of the file is:
***DBName:=MyDB
DBVersion:=ABCD-EFGH-1234

```
TotalRecords:=14

Id:=101
Time:=1678299446037
BlobLength:=12060
ÿØÿà JFIF ,,  ÿá hExif  MM *           >       F(       1       N      ,      ,   paint.net 4.3.12  ÿÛ***
etc.
```

I'm now trying to create a stored procedure to read the flat file back into the database & repopulate the table it came from. I'm stuck trying to read the blob data using UTL_FILE. Can anyone help?

UTL_FILE.GET_LINE is fine for reading the text lines, so I thought I could use it to read the blob data & use 'CONCAT' to paste it together until I've got the right number of bytes. It seems to start working & then part way through I get "*Routine "UTL_FILE.IMP_GET_LINE" (specific name "UTL_FILE_IMP_GET_LINE") has returned an error SQLSTATE with diagnostic text "UTL_FILE.VALUE_ERROR".. SQLCODE=-443, SQLSTATE=42806, DRIVER=3.72.44*"

I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Don't use the routines designed to handle text to operate on binary data.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Do you know how to read binary data from a file within a DB2 stored procedure?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're trying to reinvent the wheel instead of using the provided export/import/load capabilities of Db2?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've tried the export & import capabilities via IBM Data Studio 4.1.4. When I check the re-imported data, it's been corrupted, & I haven't been able to find how to fix that; so I'm back to square one.

Comment: Woops! I made a mistake. Please ignore my last comment. The export/import function is working, so I can use that instead of the stored procedure - even though it gives me less control. I still think it's poor that there doesn't seem to be a way to read byte data from a file within a stored procedure.